# How to use a module in libre office basic?

Tags: excel, vba, libreoffice, worksheet-function, basic

I'm used to VBA, but I am supposed to debug some libre office basic code, so I tried to write a basic module in the code-behind to address my worksheet.

The thing is, that whenever I try to run the module it seems, that it doesn't know where the starting point is etc., when I start this code in excel vba, it runs easily.. Maybe someone knows how to handle modules in libre office and why there is a main method..

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main
    Test()
End Sub


Sub Test    
    Dim MyStringVariable As String
    MyStringVariable = "Wow!"
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = MyStringVariable
End Sub
```

Comment: `dim document   as objectdim dispatcher as object
 rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 rem get access to the document
 document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
 dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
 
 rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
 args1(0).Name = "ToPoint"
 args1(0).Value = "$a$1"
 
 dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args1())`

**Here's the same logic for libre office^^**

Comment: Not quite the same logic. This code does not work with Worksheets (1), but with ActiveSheet. This is not LibreOffice code, this is a "script for the Dispatcher". You can think of this as just a record of keystrokes, nothing more. This is not enough for full-fledged programming. If you decide to get serious about open offices, then check out [**Pitonyak's book**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt). Do not read this in a row, choose the chapters you need for the given moment according to the table of contents (I started this way myself).

Comment: Alright thanks, however I actually were recording this macro in the comments via libre office and it automatically created it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the modules do not carry any functional load - this is only for the convenience of dividing the procedures and functions of your project into logically related code groups.

Your code cannot work because this Basic does not know Worksheets, it gets all sheets of the current spreadsheet using the ThisComponent.GetSheets() method. The elements of collections here are numbered from 0, not from 1, as you are used to in the VBA (this also applies to the sheets of the book, and the numbers of rows and columns):

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main
' This is just "template" - you can leave it empty, or remove it, or fill with code '
End Sub

Sub Test    
    Dim MyStringVariable As String
    MyStringVariable = "Wow!"
    ThisComponent.GetSheets().getByIndex(0).getCellRangeByName("A1").setString(MyStringVariable)
' Better write this as '
Dim oSheets As Variant
Dim oSheet As Variant
Dim oCell As Variant
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
    oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0)
    oCell.setString(MyStringVariable)
End Sub
```